# Problem with 'Getting started with Android SDK' + any Compose Spotify SDK tutorials?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, spotify, spotify-app

I am trying to find a way to use the Spotify SDK in Android using Jetpack Compose in Kotlin. All the resources I've found till now about this seem to use Views and not Compose.

I still did the Spotify Get Started tutorial below: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/tutorials/getting-started

I deviated from it in the following significant ways:

- I inherited my class from ComponentActivity() because AppCompatActivity() was crashing the app.
- I called a composable I made instead of setContentView()
- The part explaining how to import the spotify-app-remote-release-0.8.0.aar file seems to be for another version of AndroidStudio, so I imported it as below:
  https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#psd-add-aar-jar-dependency

I registered my app on Spotify for Developers, whitelisted the redirect URI and uploaded a SHA1 fingerprint.

I'm testing this app on my phone (Pixel 5 Android 14) with Spotify installed and logged into my premium account.

The app launches but no music comes out. Furthermore, the app doesn't seem to ever execute  `override fun onConnected()` or `override fun onFailure()` according to logcat. Instead it's generating a lot of spotify related errors, some of which I'm posting below my code:

So here are my questions:

- Any idea why code does not work?
- Do you know of any other SpotifySDK for Android courses working with Jetpack Compose on Kotlin?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
package com.example.spotifyandroidsdk
/* Unused tutorial imports:
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.spotify.protocol.client.Subscription;
import com.spotify.protocol.types.PlayerState;
 */
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement   
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import com.example.spotifyandroidsdk.ui.theme.SpotifyAndroidSDKTheme
import com.spotify.android.appremote.api.ConnectionParams
import com.spotify.android.appremote.api.Connector
import com.spotify.android.appremote.api.SpotifyAppRemote
import com.spotify.protocol.types.Track

//class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val clientId = "95583e167c84558e0fab519aede646b9"
    private val redirectUri = "com.example.spotifyandroidsdk://callback"
    private var spotifyAppRemote: SpotifyAppRemote? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setContent { SpotifyAndroidSDKTheme { HomeScreen() } }
    }
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val connectionParams = ConnectionParams.Builder(clientId)
            .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .showAuthView(true)
            .build()

        SpotifyAppRemote.connect(this, connectionParams, object : Connector.ConnectionListener {
            override fun onConnected(appRemote: SpotifyAppRemote) {
                spotifyAppRemote = appRemote
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Connected! Yay!")
                connected()
            }
            override fun onFailure(throwable: Throwable) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onFailure()")
                Log.e("MainActivity", throwable.message, throwable)
            }
        })
    }
    private fun connected() {
        spotifyAppRemote?.let {
            val playlistURI = "spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX2sUQwD7tbmL"
            it.playerApi.play(playlistURI)
            it.playerApi.subscribeToPlayerState().setEventCallback {
                val track: Track = it.track
                Log.d("MainActivity", track.name + " by " + track.artist.name)
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        spotifyAppRemote?.let {
            SpotifyAppRemote.disconnect(it)
        }
    }
}
// I added this myself...
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello Spotify!")
    }

}
```

Logcat errors:

```
2023-12-18 18:06:24.735  2552-2595  OpenGLRenderer          com.android.systemui                 E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-12-18 18:06:25.131 28784-6507  Spotify                 com.spotify.music                    E  [network@f:437] AP Socket Error: Software caused connection abort (103)
2023-12-18 18:06:25.131 28784-6507  Spotify                 com.spotify.music                    E  [network@f:758] Connection error: ap_socket_reset
2023-12-18 18:06:25.141 28784-6512  Spotify                 com.spotify.music                    E  [logging@f:221] aq: OnError reason: 1, error:Connection closed by peer
2023-12-18 18:06:25.205 28784-6505  Spotify                 com.spotify.music                    E  [Core Thread@connect:459] ConnectConnectivityListener: received empty connection_id
2023-12-18 18:06:25.388 12022-12041 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.spotifyandroidsdk        E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-12-18 18:06:25.943  1731-4241  ActivityTaskManager     system_server                        E  Abort background activity starts from 10242
2023-12-18 18:06:25.984 28784-6505  Spotify                 com.spotify.music                    E  [Core Thread@connect:463] ConnectConnectivityListener: received new_connection_id Y2VmYTJiMjUtYWJkMC00OTYxLWE5YTQtZjQ3N2U5MjBlODhhK2RlYWxlcit0Y3A6Ly9nZXcxLWRlYWxlci1hLXJnODIuZ2V3MS5zcG90aWZ5Lm5ldDo1NzAwKzg2RDU0QjgyNEExNjY2QUY4NTg4OTI5REIxQzUxOTM0RTZDMDdFNzkxNThDN0I1ODlGQkM3MjQxNUI2MjU0RDc= - starting 
2023-12-18 18:06:26.024  1731-1994  DiscreteRegistry        system_server                        E  Deleting file 1702313906375tl
2023-12-18 18:06:26.025  1731-1994  DiscreteRegistry        system_server                        E  Deleting file 1702314138660tl
2023-12-18 18:06:28.855 14166-14227 OneSearchS...stProvider com...le.android.apps.nexuslauncher  E  Failed to fetch suggestions from AppSearch, fallback to AGA
                                                                                                    java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:323)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:684)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:486)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2138)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.allapps.H0.onResult(Unknown Source:59)
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.lambda$onResult$0(SearchSessionUtil.java:129)
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.$r8$lambda$_nlk9WiPjSfaAsqKYmp0aPvSRC0(SearchSessionUtil.java:1)
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:13)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
                                                                                                        at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:144)
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.allapps.H0.onResult(Unknown Source:16)
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.lambda$onResult$0(SearchSessionUtil.java:129) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1.$r8$lambda$_nlk9WiPjSfaAsqKYmp0aPvSRC0(SearchSessionUtil.java:1) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.appsearch.SearchSessionUtil$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(R8$$SyntheticClass:13) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
2023-12-18 18:06:28.866 28784-12073 Spotify                 com.spotify.music                    E  [pool-161-thread-1] Could not send the message to the remote client
2023-12-18 18:06:28.871 14166-14216 OpenGLRenderer          com...le.android.apps.nexuslauncher  E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2023-12-18 18:06:29.213   661-661   BpTransact...edListener surfaceflinger                       E  Failed to transact (-32)
```